# Error 'nf90_def_var_deflate has no IMPLICIT type' only on one computer

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran, netcdf

I have some code which compiles fine on one machine but on a different machine (using the same compilers, gcc and gfortran, and same flags) I get an error which I can't understand how it is compile related:

```
 deflate_status = nf90_def_var_deflate(NCF%ncid, i, 0, 1, 7)
                  1
 Error: Function 'nf90_def_var_deflate' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

The variable is definitely declared (and it compiles and runs on the first machine). What sort of problems with compile setup could cause this error?

Comment: Use tag fortran to get more attention. Fortran 90 is just one old version.

Comment: How do you include the NetCDF headers or modules? Show the code!

Comment: What version(s) of NetCDF are you using?  Variable compression was introduced at version 4.

Comment: There's also a weird chance that it wasn't compiled with netCDF4. There should be a utility `nc-config` which will tell you what your configuration is. It will be in the `bin` directory of your netCDF installation. So something like `/usr/local/netcdf/bin/nc-config --all` will tell you what is going on. If this command doesn't exist then it's odds on you have an old pre V4 installation.