# Fortran Error: Function 'nf90_def_var_deflate' has no implicit type

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, netcdf4

I am trying to compile a model run using the CESM 2.1.0 model and I have been running into a compiler error related to the netcdf settings but I do not know which settings I should change. 
The Error is: 
Error: Function 'nf90_def_var_deflate' has no implicit type. 
The function is definitely defined and the code should work as this is a scientific research model used by a larger community.

I read another question where the person has the same problem but there is no solution as of yet.

[Error 'nf90_def_var_deflate has no IMPLICIT type' only on one computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653810/error-nf90-def-var-deflate-has-no-implicit-type-only-on-one-computer)

I checked the netcdf configuration as recommended in the question above and this is the output:

```
$ nc-config --all

This netCDF 4.6.3 has been built with the following features:

  --cc            -> mpicc
  --cflags        -> -I/apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel/include
  --libs          -> -L/apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel/lib -lnetcdf

  --has-c++       -> no
  --cxx           ->

  --has-c++4      -> no
  --cxx4          ->

  --has-fortran   -> yes
  --fc            -> mpifort
  --fflags        -> -I/apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel/include
  --flibs         -> -L/apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel/lib -lnetcdff -L/apps/hdf5/1.10.5/parallel/lib -lnetcdf -lcurl -lm -lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz -ldl
  --has-f90       -> no
  --has-f03       -> yes

  --has-dap       -> yes
  --has-dap2      -> yes
  --has-dap4      -> yes
  --has-nc2       -> yes
  --has-nc4       -> yes
  --has-hdf5      -> yes
  --has-hdf4      -> no
  --has-logging   -> no
  --has-pnetcdf   -> no
  --has-szlib     -> no
  --has-cdf5      -> yes
  --has-parallel4 -> yes
  --has-parallel  -> yes

  --prefix        -> /apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel
  --includedir    -> /apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel/include
  --libdir        -> /apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel/lib
  --version       -> netCDF 4.6.3
```

Edit: 
Here ist the configuration of the netcdf-fortran:

```
 nf-config --all

This netCDF-Fortran 4.4.5 has been built with the following features:

  --cc        -> gcc
  --cflags    ->  -I/apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel/include

  --fc        -> mpifort
  --fflags    -> -I/apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel/include
  --flibs     -> -L/apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel/lib -lnetcdff -L/apps/hdf5/1.10.5/parallel/lib -lnetcdf -lcurl -lm -lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz -ldl
  --has-f90   -> no
  --has-f03   -> yes

  --has-nc2   -> yes
  --has-nc4   -> no

  --prefix    -> /apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel
  --includedir-> /apps/netcdf/netcdf-4.6.0_gcc-4.8.5/parallel/include
  --version   -> netCDF-Fortran 4.4.5
```

Edit #2:
Here is the code snippet where the function is called:

```
if(iotype==pio_iotype_netcdf4c) then
                if(vardesc%ndims>0 .and. ierr==PIO_NOERR) then
                   ierr = nf90_def_var_deflate(File%fh,vardesc%varid,0,1,1)
                end if
             endif
```

The reason I believe that the CESM model is using the right netcdf version is because the log output says: `Checking NetCDF version - 4.6.3./*!<`

Comment: We need to see the code. How is the type of the function defined? In a module or in an include file? Now I see I can basically just repeat the comment from the other question: *"How do you include the NetCDF headers or modules? Show the code! "*

Comment: What happens if you temporarily define the function as `integer`? Does any other compiler or linker error appear?

Comment: Possible version conflict? Claims to be NetCDF 4.6.3, but is compiled from directory suggesting 4.6.0. Could be an indication that there are two different NetCDF versions on the computer.

Comment: @chw21 I understand the irritation but the version used it 4.6.3 which is installed in that directory for some reason.

Comment: This would happen if you linked to a classic only version of the netCDF fortran library - one that was built with a netcdf C library which was built with --disable-netcdf-4.

Comment: @EdwardHartnett do you think the fact that the netcdf fortran configuration says --has-nc4 is the problem?

Comment: The --has-nc4 means that that netcdf-fortran was built with a netcdf-c library which had netcdf-4 enabled (the default) and so the function nf90_def_var_deflate should be present. But it looks to me like you are not really linking to the netCDF library you think you are. (Also did you include the proper use statement? It would be nice to see some of the fortran code that generated this error).